# App showing wrong language on some iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, localization

I'm having a problem and just can't figure out what is causing it.

My iOS app is localized (English, Spanish and Brazilian Portuguese). It became available on the app store a few hours ago and three of my Brazilian friends (living in Brazil, with their iPhones language set to Portuguese) got the app in English.

On the app store, the app description and screenshots show up in Portuguese, like they should, but on the homescreen that app has its name in English, and when you open it, everything is english **but the date**, which shows up correctly.

What is even odder is that the app is in Portuguese for the five other people that downloaded the app in Brazil (me included).

**The only thing in common the iPhones that are in English have is that they are iPhone 5s, while all the others are not (5, 6 and 6 plus), but I don't really think this should affect it in any way (right?)*

Anyways... as you may have seen, I'm Brazilian, so please tell me if I was not clear describring the problem. Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** *A friend with an iPhone 6 also has the app showing up in English.

Answer (score 2):

This issue effects iOS 8 users that have Spanish anywhere in their list of preferred languages. So if their preferred language order is (English, Spanish), for whatever reason the app loads in Spanish for them. A quick fix for specific users is to just have them remove Spanish from the Preferred Language Order in the iOS Settings App under General->Language & Region.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the reason. The localization is not working to anyone on iOS 8. Now I need to find out why and how to fix it.